# Python & Kivy: Camera and Coming Texts in Different Screens

Tags: python, camera, synchronization, kivy, screen

I want to build an app with Kivy in Python but I got some errors that I tried to solve many times but I can't.

I'm opening a camera screen firstly. In screen, we see our webcam screen and there is 2 buttons at the bottom (Play and Capture). While I pressing Play, webcam is on and if I press Capture button, I'm taking snapshot. After taking snapshot, we are going to the screen which is located on the left. Special thanks to [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8864220/erik) , he built this working code below.

But when I capture the photo and we are in the left screen, I want to show some text (coming from ANOTHER py file for example basic hello1, hello2... whatever) in left screen.

I know that how can I print basically a sentence in just Console with only print function but I want to write many print function's results in my application on the left screen synchronously from ANOTHER py file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import time

class CheckScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CameraClickScreen(Screen):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


GUI = Builder.load_string("""

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        CameraClickScreen:
            name: "camera_click_screen"
            id: camera_click_screen
        CheckScreen:
            name: "check_screen"
            id: check_screen



<CameraClickScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (640, 480)
            play: False
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Play'
            on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Capture'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_press:
                root.capture()
                # root refers to <CameraClickScreen>
                # app refers to TestCamera, app.root refers to the GridLayout: at the top
                app.root.ids['screen_manager'].transition.direction = 'left'
                app.root.ids['screen_manager'].current = 'check_screen'

<CheckScreen>:
    Button:
        text: "Next Screen"
        font_size: 50
""")

class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return GUI


TestCamera().run()
```

Normally with this code, on the left screen, we see "Next Screen" sentence with a button. I want to see variable texts coming from py file. For example Hello 1, and clear the screen, Hello 2, and clear the screen, ..., Hello 5 and stop.

How can I add this basic print functions and integrate with app to show us on the left screen?

Comment: So you want to change the text in the button each time you take a picture? Is that correct?

Comment: almost yes. after taking picture and while we are on the next screen, normally my other main code will run on the backside. in the end of the code normally it shows some sentences with print function on the console. I want to see these sentences on the left screen.

Comment: you can use the `.text` property to change the text inside of a button or label. You can reference your widget using its id. I think that's what you want to do